# Can we able to access ODB++ files( PCB ) in C++/ VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can we able to access ODB++ files in C++/ VC++ ?

PCB - printed circuit board manufacturing database

Has any one done this before ??
Any library files available in internet to access / read this ODB++ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library for VC++ to load and handle ODB++ files (and some others like Gerber or IPC2581).

Take a look at the the API from [PCB-Investigator](http://www.pcb-investigator.com/sdk-participate).